# Mouseenter failing after hovering over a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hover

I have a function that adds a information div when I hover over a text paragraph, but when I go from normal text in the paragraph to a hyperlink the mouseover event stops and wont restart until my mouse leaves the paragraph and re-hover over it. It will display if I start on the link but it will always stop if I go from a link to text or text to the link.

Paragraph examples:

```
<div id="NoteHolder">
    <div class="wrap">
        <p class="NoteOp inline date1471280868332">Example sentence <a target="_blank" class="a" href="https://www.example.com">https://www.example.com</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I hover over the paragraph it converts the date number class into a human readable date and it is displayed in a div.

Mouseover event:

```
$('#NoteHolder').on( "mouseenter", ".NoteOp", function() {
    var Info = document.createElement('div');
    Info.className = 'EditInfo'
    var DateP = document.createElement('p');
    DateP.className = 'DivP';
    var DatePT = document.createTextNode(PT)
    DateP.appendChild(DatePT);
    Info.appendChild(DateP);
    var position = $(this).position();
    var thisX = position.left;
    var thisY = position.top;
    var thisWidth = $(this).width();
    var thisHeight = $(this).height();
    var PageW = $('html').width();
    if(thisX + thisWidth + 50 > PageW) {
        $(Info).css({
            "left": thisX + thisWidth + 20,
            "top": thisY - 10
        });
    }
    document.getElementById("NoteHolder").appendChild(Info);
});

$('#NoteHolder').on( "mouseout", ".NoteOp", function() {
    $(".EditInfo").remove();
});
```

Is there anyway to fix this from removing the div when I hover over links?

Comment: Jsfiddle of the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/ygxvcp3g/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo mistake in your code, extra closing bracket which causes this issue, below is the corrected code

```js
$(function() {
$('#NoteHolder').on( "mouseover", ".NoteOp", function() {
    alert("Enter");
    var Info = document.createElement('div');
    Info.className = 'EditInfo'
    var DateP = document.createElement('p');
    DateP.className = 'DivP';
    var DatePT = document.createTextNode(PT)
    DateP.appendChild(DatePT);
    Info.appendChild(DateP);
    var position = $(this).position();
    var thisX = position.left;
    var thisY = position.top;
    var thisWidth = $(this).width();
    var thisHeight = $(this).height();
    var PageW = $('html').width();
    if(thisX + thisWidth + 50 > PageW) {
        $(Info).css({
            "left": thisX + thisWidth + 20,
            "top": thisY - 10
        });
    }
    document.getElementById("NoteHolder").appendChild(Info);
   
});

$('#NoteHolder').on( "mouseout", ".NoteOp", function() {
    alert("Exit");
    $(".EditInfo").remove();
});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="NoteHolder">
    <div class="wrap">
        <p class="NoteOp inline date1471280868332">Example sentence <a target="_blank" class="a" href="https://www.example.com">https://www.example.com</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you are using a jQuery, you can create a dynamic div by `$("<div/>")` rather than `document.createElement('div')`

Comment: It still doesn't work, I fixed the bracket but I made a jsfiddle and it still doesn't fix it. https://jsfiddle.net/ygxvcp3g/

Comment: Still doesn't work when I start hovering over text, then move and hover over the link.